# SPSS 22. Sort data

Tags: sorting, statistics, spss

After asking 16 questions (yes or no) to 75 people I have a table of their answers coded like 00110011110101010 ('0'=no and '1'=yes). 
Now I would like to find groups of people who answered in the most similar way (ideally to find all groups with similitudes from 16/16 to 12/16).

How to do this in SPSS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm unsure what `similitudes from 16/16 to 12/16` means. This may be better for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it is not asking for specific programming help - but a more general statistics question. A good start is to sort the questions by some criteria and then sort the rows. You can then plot a [binary heat map](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95556/1036) of the responses by people to see if any patterns emerge.

Comment: There exists different ways to sort the matrices though, see [Pilhofer et al. (2012)](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~raghu/teaching/CSE5544/Visweek2012/infovis/papers/pilhoefer.pdf) for one example (although that is for a contingency table).

Comment: Oh thanks. 
"There is an example figure taken from Wilkinson & Friendly (2009) but is originally from the work of Bertin:"
It would be great to do like in that example because in my .doc I have similar matrix but I dont know how :)

Answer (score 1):

I will answer how to replicate that particular plot you mention in SPSS - but of course there are other types of analysis you could proceed to conduct. So here is a bit of a lengthy code to create a set of binary responses for 75 people, and they are drawn from 3 distinct groups.

```
*************************************.
*Making fake data with 3 groups.
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP Case = 1 TO 75.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
FORMATS Case (F2.0).

*Making a mixture of 3 groups.
COMPUTE Group = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,4)).
SORT CASES BY Group.
*Making a set of random data.
VECTOR Bin(16,F1.0).
VECTOR QP(16).
DO REPEAT QP = QP1 TO QP16.
DO IF $casenum = 1 OR (Group <> LAG(Group)).
  COMPUTE QP = RV.UNIFORM(0,1).
ELSE.
  COMPUTE QP = LAG(QP).
END IF.
END REPEAT.
DO REPEAT Bin = Bin1 TO Bin16 /QP = QP1 TO QP16.
  COMPUTE Bin = RV.BERNOULLI(QP).
END REPEAT.
MATCH FILES FILE = * /DROP Group QP1 TO QP16.
SORT CASES BY Case.
EXECUTE.
*************************************.
```

Now to make our plot we are going to reshape the data from wide to long using `VARSTOCASES`.

```
*Reshaping and then plotting in a matrix.
VARSTOCASES
  /MAKE Bin FROM Bin1 TO Bin16
  /INDEX Question.
VALUE LABELS Bin
  0 'No'
  1 'Yes'.
```

Now that our data is in long format we can make our [binary heat map](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95556/1036).

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Question Case Bin
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Question=col(source(s), name("Question"), unit.category())
  DATA: Case=col(source(s), name("Case"), unit.category())
  DATA: Bin=col(source(s), name("Bin"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Question"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Case"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Default Ordering"))
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("0",color.white),("1",color.darkgrey)))
  ELEMENT: polygon(position(Question*Case), color.interior(Bin))
END GPL.
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: Default Binary Heat Map]

Now often the plot is much more informative by some simple ordering (as is referenced in the CV post). The one I show below is to simply sort the scores the cases and the questions by the mean number of "Yes" answers. It produces a somewhat more orderly chart - but my three groups are still not obviously visible.

```
*Sorting by number answered yes per person and then by yes per question.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * MODE = ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK = Case
  /MeanC = MEAN(Bin).
SORT CASES BY MeanC.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE = * MODE = ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK = Question
  /MeanQ = MEAN(Bin).
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Question Case Bin MeanQ
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Question=col(source(s), name("Question"), unit.category())
  DATA: Case=col(source(s), name("Case"), unit.category())
  DATA: Bin=col(source(s), name("Bin"), unit.category())
  DATA: MeanQ=col(source(s), name("MeanQ"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Question"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Case"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Order By Mean Number per Case and Question"))
  SCALE: cat(dim(1), sort.statistic(summary.mean(MeanQ)), reverse())
  SCALE: cat(dim(2), sort.data())
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("0",color.white),("1",color.darkgrey)))
  ELEMENT: polygon(position(Question*Case), color.interior(Bin))
END GPL.
```

[image: Ordered Map]